# bunch of errors using kotlin in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, kotlin

I'm trying to run my android app using Android studio Emulator using Kotlin programming language. It stopped suddenly and gave me few error any help ?

this is what is give me now at Event log(last 6 line are in Red color)

> 11:18 AM Gradle sync started
>
> 11:21 AM Project setup started
>
> 11:21 AM Gradle sync finished in 2m 51s 524ms
>
> 11:21 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
>
> 11:22 AM Gradle build finished in 37s 164ms
>
> 11:22 AM Configure Kotlin C:/Users/ziadm/ziadsaadApp/build.gradle was modified C:/Users/ziadm/ziadsaadApp/app/build.gradle was modified
>
> 11:22 AM Gradle sync started
>
> 11:23 AM Project setup started
>
> 11:23 AM Gradle sync finished in 10s 332ms
>
> 11:23 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
>
> 11:23 AM Gradle build finished in 16s 593ms
>
> 11:24 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 11:24 AM Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
>
> 11:24 AM Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
>
> 11:24 AM Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
>
> 11:24 AM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
>
> 11:24 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
>
> 11:25 AM Gradle build finished in 54s 739ms

Comment: So the issue is not related to Kotlin and it's about your Android Emulator not being able to start at all. Google `0xc0000005 android emulator` to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with emulated Performance. Put as it is on image.

[image]

Comment: Thats amazing Friend Now and for the first time its running perfectly 
Just one more Question i have 8GB RAM on my Pc how much i shall dedicated for the emulator to run smoothly?

Comment: its running But i have this error
12:41 PM Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
???

Comment: for the last question create the new virtual device and enable the snapshot, unchecke the checkbox Go to AVD Manager -> Select the device -> click Edit and uncheck the Enabled checkbox. If it still doesnot work update your gpu drivers.

Comment: is it working? if yes please dont forget to accept and upvote ;)

Comment: I am afraid you didn`t))

Comment: Ohh I thing u cannot upvote, if answer is what u wanted just accept it by clicking accpet